# Invalid argument in ssh_options_set when connect mysql via navicat ssh tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, navicat

I use navicat ssh tunnel to connect mysql, but I got the error "Invalid argument in ssh_options_set". The remote server is in LAN.

But when I change the server to outer net server, it is fine to connect mysql via ssh tunnel in navicat.

So is there any difference between LAN and outer net when I use SSH tunnel in navicat？I also wonder how can I get the ssh command navicat generate, so I can test it myself.

My environment macos 10.13, navicat version is premium 12.1.10. The settings as show in the picture[image]

BTW, I can use two weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

1.edit sshd configuration file：

`vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

find：#UseDNS yes

delete comment '#' prefix，change `yes` to `no`

```
UseDNS no
```

2.restart sshd：

```
service sshd restart
```

this resolves my problem, good luck~